# Failed test. Wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, обработка-ошибок

Извините за большой текст , я новенький , учу питон и пытаюсь решить задачу только теми способами , которые нам дали на обучении.

Задача на Stepik:

Узнав, что ДНК не является случайной строкой, только что поступившие в Институт биоинформатики студенты группы информатиков предложили использовать алгоритм сжатия, который сжимает повторяющиеся символы в строке.
Кодирование осуществляется следующим образом:
s = 'aaaabbсaa' преобразуется в 'a4b2с1a2', то есть группы одинаковых символов исходной строки заменяются на этот символ и количество его повторений в этой позиции строки.
Напишите программу, которая считывает строку, кодирует её предложенным алгоритмом и выводит закодированную последовательность на стандартный вывод. Кодирование должно учитывать регистр символов

1)Не могу пройти один из тестов, все проверки которые мог придумать я реализовал( в том числе и на неверный символ ), но получаю ошибку:

Failed test #6 of 15. Wrong answer

2)Не совсем понимаю условие "Кодирование должно учитывать регистр символов" , что оно должно значить

Мой код:

```
s = input()
s = s.lower()

n = 0
j = 0
i = 0
ia = 0
ib = 0
ic = 0
simv_err = 0

# проверка всей строки на неверный символ

while j <= len(s)-1 :  
    if s[j] == 'a' or s[j] == 'b' or s[j] == 'c':
        j += 1
    else :
        j += 1
        simv_err += 1
if simv_err > 0 : 
    print('Неверный символ')
    
#если все символы в строке верные , начинаем считать

else :
    while i <= (len(s)-1) : 
            if s[i] == 'a' :
                i += 1
                ia += 1
                if i > (len(s)-1) or s[i] != 'a':
                    ic = 0
                    ib = 0
                    print("a",end='')
                    print(ia,end='')
            elif s[i] == 'b' :
                i += 1
                ib += 1
                ia = 0
                if i > (len(s)-1) or s[i] != 'b' :
                    ic = 0
                    ia = 0
                    print("b",end='')
                    print(ib,end='')
            elif s[i] == 'c' :
                i += 1
                ic += 1
                ib = 0
                ia = 0
                if i > (len(s)-1) or s[i] != 'c' :
                    ia = 0
                    ib = 0
                    print("c",end='')
                    print(ic,end='')
```

Comment: `s = s.lower()` — вот здесь вы точно ломаете учёт регистра символов

Comment: А ещё из условия задачи не следует, что abc это единственные возможные символы

Comment: Судя по ошибке дело не в проверках, никакие проверки там вроде не требуются. "Кодирование должно учитывать регистр символов" - ну, скорее всего 'A' и 'a' должны считаться как разные символы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Кодирование должно учитывать регистр символов

Означает что большие и маленькие буквы должны считаться отдельно:

```
"aaaabbсaa" -> "a4b2с1a2"
"aAaabbсaa" -> "a1A1a2b2с1a2"
```

Решил эту задачу двумя способами:

```
#  "Питоновский" подход - использование zip().
#  Для упрощения кода в конец строки добавляется нулевой байт -
#  это позволяет обработать последнюю букву внутри цикла без каких-либо
#  дополнительных проверок.
#  Условие - строка не должна содержать нулевых байтов.
def dna_compress_1(s):
    compressed_s = ''
    cnt = 0

    s += '\x00'
    
    for cur, nxt in zip(s, s[1:]):
        cnt += 1
    
        if cur != nxt:
            compressed_s += cur + str(cnt)
            cnt = 0

    return compressed_s

#  Классический подход - использование индексов
def dna_compress_2(s):
    compressed_s = ''
    cnt = 0
    size = len(s)

    i = 0
    while i < size:
        cnt += 1
        #  Если текущая буква не равна следующей или
        #  текущая буква является последней - запиши
        #  эту букву вместе с её счётчиком в сжатую строку.
        if i == size - 1 or s[i] != s[i + 1]:
            compressed_s += s[i] + str(cnt)
            cnt = 0

        i += 1

    return compressed_s
```

**Тестирование**

```
test_lst = [
    "aaaabbсaa",
    "aAaabbсaa",
    "a",
    "ab",
    "abb"
]

for test_str in test_lst:
    print(dna_compress_1(test_str))
    print(dna_compress_2(test_str))
    print()
```

**Вывод**

```
a4b2с1a2
a4b2с1a2

a1A1a2b2с1a2
a1A1a2b2с1a2

a1
a1

a1b1
a1b1

a1b2
a1b2
```